# executar lista de arquivos python com script shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Meu código:

```
#!/bin/bash

scriptspy =(
    '/scs/sp1.py',
    '/scs/sp2.py',
    '/scs/sp3.py',
    '/scs/sp4.py',
    '/scs/spweb.py',
    '/scs/sp11.py',
    '/scs/spservice.py',
    ....
)

for i in scriptspy;
  do python3.7 $i;
done
```

Meu objetivo é executar uma lista de arquivos que possuem python no diretório e não precisam executar um por um individualmente com `python3.7 sp1.py`

Obs: Não posso executar todos os arquivos .py no diretório, preciso passar uma lista para o loop com o nome deles, ou uma lista que não podem ser executados, tenho ao todo 28 quero executar e 3 que não quero executar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código estava quase certo.

```
#!/bin/bash

scriptspy=(
    '/scs/sp1.py',
    '/scs/sp2.py',
    '/scs/sp3.py',
    '/scs/sp4.py',
    '/scs/spweb.py',
    '/scs/sp11.py',
    '/scs/spservice.py'
)

for i in ${scriptspy[*]};
  do python3.7 $i;
done
```